# Clock divider by 8

Tags: verilog, clock, divider

I have 1 module for click divider by 2

```
module divider_by2 ( clk ,rst,out_clk );
    output reg out_clk;
    input clk, rst;

    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        if (~rst) out_clk <= 1'b0;
        else out_clk <= ~out_clk;   
    end

endmodule
```

Now I want to reuse this module for making clock divider by 8

```
module top(clk, rst, out_clk);
    output reg out_clk;
    input clk, rst;

    wire out_clk1;
    wire out_clk2;

    divider_by2 obj1(clk, rst, out_clk1);
    divider_by2 obj2(out_clk1, rst, out_clk2);
    divider_by2 obj3(out_clk2, rst, out_clk);

endmodule
```

And tb for top module

```
module divtb ();
    wire out_clk;
    reg clk, rst;

    top topp(clk, rst, out_clk);

    initial begin
      $dumpfile("dd.vcd");
      $dumpvars(0, divtb);

      clk = 0;
      #1 reset = 1;
      #1 reset = 0;

     #125;
     $finish;
    end
   always
    #1 clk = !clk;
 endmodule
```

Getting error:

> d.v:23:        reg out_clk; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment.
>
> d.v:23: error: Output port expression must support continuous
>   assignment.
>
> d.v:23:      : Port out_clk of divider_by2 is connected to out_clk 2
>   error(s) during elaboration.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

You have the register in divider_by2 module, so you don't need the register in top module to expose the last divider's output.

Just drop that `reg` in top module's out_clk output.